# Why does my print statement only work inside of a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

Upon inputting a number, nothing happens. if I put the print statement inside one of the conditional statements, it prints it, but it will print it as many times as it loops.

Really curious about what is happening and how I can print the final list just one time in the simplest way.

```
number = input('Enter a Number')
newList = []

for i in range(1,10000000000001):

    if int(number) % i == 0:
        newList.append(i)


print(newList)
```

Comment: How long do you think it takes to count to 10000000000001?

Comment: What happened when you used a debugger?

Comment: Have you waited long enough? A loop testing for odd numbers (and including an `int()` call) is not done instantaneously.

Comment: You're looping 10^13 times before you print anything.  Depending on your hardware, this could take a few days.  You're also slowing down the loop by a redundant conversion to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't waited long enough, your loop isn't done yet.

You are looping 10 ^ 13, or 10 [trillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(numbers)#1012) times, before printing:

```
for i in range(1,10000000000001):
```

That'll take Python a while, executing the loop body has a cost. On my laptop (a 2017  MacBook Pro with 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7 processor), I can run your loop body 10 million times in about 1 and a quarter second:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(
...     "int(number) % i == 0",  # loop body code
...     "number = 42; i = 43",   # set values for the variables
...     number=10**7)            # number of repetitions to time
1.259572982788086
```

10 trillion repetitions would take 10 ** 6 (1 million) times longer, so about 1259573 seconds.

1259573 seconds is 349 hours, 52 minutes and 53 seconds:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> print(timedelta(seconds=1.259573 * 10 ** 6))
14 days, 13:52:53
```

You'll have to wait 2 weeks and 14 hours, before the loop is done!

You don't need to loop that often. If you are trying to find the divisors of a number, you only need to loop up to the *square root of the number*, because you can always find the 'other' divisor' by dividing `number` by the divisor again. The square root is the highest value a divisor can get before `number // divisor` produces numbers that are smaller than the divisor (and thus have already been tested):

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: ")
for i in range(1, int(number ** 0.5) + 1):            
    if number % i == 0:
        # i is a divisor
        print(i, end=' ')
        # so is number // i
        j = number // i
        # but test if it is different from i
        if j != i:
            print(j, end=' ')
```

This prints out the divisors in a different order, of course:

```
Enter a number: 1002001
1 1002001 7 143143 11 91091 13 77077 49 20449 77 13013 91 11011 121 8281 143 7007 169 5929 539 1859 637 1573 847 1183 1001
```

You could reduce the number of iterations even further; odd numbers can only have odd divisors, so you may as well *skip all the even numbers*.

The following sets a step size for `range()`, either `1` (for even numbers) or `2` (for odd numbers):

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: ")
for i in range(1, int(number ** 0.5) + 1, 1 + (number % 2)):            
    if number % i == 0:
        # i is a divisor
        print(i, end=' ')
        # so is number // i, but test if it is different
        j = number // i
        if j != i:
            print(j, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try printing as you go, with the `end` parameter.  Also, stop when you hit the number you're processing.

```
number = int(input('Enter a number'))

for i in range(1, min(10000000000001, number + 1)):

    if number % i == 0:
        print(i, end = ' ')
```

Output, given 1002001 as input:

```
Enter a number1002001
1 7 11 13 49 77 91 121 143 169 539 637 847 1001 1183 1573 1859 5929 7007 8281 11011 13013 20449 77077 91091 143143 1002001
```

If you're trying to find all the factors of a number, there are much more efficient ways to do so.  Use your browser to research solutions.  "Python factor an integer" should do it.